# plotly table - one column with differnt text color

Tags: python, plotly

Hi i am looking for a solution to color the text in a specific column with plotly. i expect the first column text in blue (all integers: 1, 2, ...)

i found some solutions for conditional coloring. the conditions may that the value in the first column is a integer...

may somebody can help me. thanks a lot

```
nr = ['1', '2', '3']
text = ['Text - GESAMT', 'Text- nach Inhaber', 'GESAMT']
page = ['3-5', '6', '7']

df_inhalt = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(nr, text, page)),
                         columns=['Nr', 'Text', 'SeitenNr'])

rows_in_df = len(df_inhalt)  # to calculate high of table
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(
    header=dict(values=[],  # header is empty!
                font_size=24,
                height=50,
                fill_color='white',
                align=['left', 'right', 'center', 'center']),
    cells=dict(values=[df_inhalt.Nr, df_inhalt.Text, df_inhalt.SeitenNr],
               font_size=22,
               height=35,
               fill_color='white',
               align=['left', 'right', 'left', 'right', 'left']))])
fig.update_layout(margin=dict(l=0, r=0, t=0, b=0))
fig.update_traces(columnwidth=[5, 4, 198, 20, 20])  # 267
fig.update_layout(width=1200, height=rows_in_df * 35 + 50)

plotly.io.write_image(fig, 'inhalt.png', format='png')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try making the fill_color input a list of colors?

```
fill_color = ['blue', 'white', 'blue', 'white', 'white']
```

Comment: yes, but i mean: font=dict(color=['blue', 'black', 'black', 'black', 'black']),  thank you. may change your answer and I can accept ist